# Matcher not finding text within <> (e.g., HTML tag)

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

Does anyone know why the Matcher in Salesforce does not find text contained within `<>` (the "less than" and "greater than" signs)? The sample code below, adapted from "[Using Patterns and Matchers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)", fails the final assertion in API 29.0.

```
// First, instantiate a new Pattern object "MyPattern"
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('a*b');

// Then instantiate a new Matcher object "MyMatcher"
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher('<aaaaab>');

// You can use the system static method assert to verify the match,
// but this assertion fails because the expected match is not found
System.assert(MyMatcher.matches());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't `matches()` do a whole-string determination of whether it fits the regex? Like you might use for validating input strings? Might have more luck with the `find()` method:

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('a*b');
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher('<aaaaab>');
while(MyMatcher.find()) {
    System.debug(MyMatcher.group(0)); //"aaaaab"
}
```

Eyeballing the question for your intention, are you looking for something like this?

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('<code>([^<]+)</code>');
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher('<code>herp</code><br /><code>derp</code>');
while(MyMatcher.find()) {
    System.debug(MyMatcher.group(1)); //"herp" and "derp"
}
```

You're probably already aware of [the usual caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1606872) :-)

Comment: Thanks again for the assistance! I was wondering where you found mention of the `Matcher.find()` method, until I re-read the "Using Match Operations" page. It seems like this important method could use some more publicity in the documentation: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: np @MartyC. - I've added an example